# How do I set the documentation PDF for my package?

Tags: packages, documentation, ctan, texdoc

I wanted to check the syntax of something in one of my packages, and rather than hunt for the file on my system I just did `texdoc hobby` on the command line.  To my dismay, this brought up the PDF containing the *code*, not the main documentation.  When I submitted the package to CTAN, I split the documentation into two parts: the user documentation and the code documentation.  As the latter is produced from the `.dtx`, it gets named `hobby.pdf`, the user documentation can be named whatever I like so I chose `hobby_doc.pdf`.  It's quite reasonable that `texdoc hobby` produces `hobby.pdf` (and `texdoc hobby_doc` produces the user documentation), but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do from a user's perspective.

There seem to me to be two ways to fix this:

1. Change my filenames so that the code becomes `hobby_code.pdf` and the documentation is `hobby.pdf`.  Ideally, I'd like this to be automatic so that I still have `hobby.dtx` and `hobby.tex` but `pdflatex hobby.dtx` produces `hobby_code.pdf`.  I know that one can't change `\jobname` from within a document, but as this is a `.dtx`, I thought that maybe the compilation process isn't as simple as it seems and it might still be possible to change the output filename.  Is it?
2. Set up `texdoc` so that `texdoc hobby` points to `hobby_doc.pdf`.  This, as I understand it, is eminently possible but it would need doing officially.  So how do I go about making such a change and is it a simple thing to ask for?  (If complicated, then clearly I should use Option 1 even if I can't do so automatically.)

Comment: What does `texdoc -l hobby` report? I assume the TL team have spotted both.

Comment: When I type `texdoc hobby` I see `hobby_doc.pdf`.  As I haven't updated my packages in a few months, perhaps something in one of the updates caused this.

Comment: @JosephWright It reports (in order) `hobby.pdf`, `hobby_doc.pdf`, and `README`.  I presume that this part is automatic in that it looks for all pdfs (and other standard files) in the submitted `doc` directory.  My point about my parenthetical remark is that I don't want to make a nuisance of myself with the CTAN/TL team, so if there's a "right" way to do this then I'll follow that.

Comment: I get this from `texdoc hobby`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WcTMs.png and through winedt help menu this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bs0Rw.png

Comment: This is why the documented code for `glossaries` and `datatool` are now called `glossaries-code.pdf` and `datatool-code.pdf`. :-) I've switched to using `pdflatex -jobname glossaries-code glossaries.dtx` etc to compile the code.

Comment: @HarishKumar Interesting!  Which TeX distribution are you using (TL or MikTeX?).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Right, so that's the manual solution.  I was wondering if there was an automatic one.  I guess I could just use `arara`!

Comment: Andrew: I use MikTeX which I updated 2 days ago.

Comment: @AndrewStacey It's only manual in the sense that I manually edited the script I use to bundle up my distributions when I made the switch :-) But I think this is an important issue for complex packages as there may be new users obediently using `texdoc foo` only to be freaked out by the documented code instead of being presented with a nice friendly user guide.

Comment: From time to time there are requests on the TL-list to set another default for texdoc for a specific package (because of similar »wrong« default documentation). I guess you could do the same

Comment: @cgnieder The texdoc mailing list is probably a better place for texdoc-related requests: https://www.tug.org/texdoc/

Comment: @mpg sure... I'm not on the texdoc  list but I saw a few such messages on the tl list which is why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen requests from time to time on the [Tex Live list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live) by authors as well as by users to set another default for `texdoc` for a specific package (because of similarly »wrong« default documentation). You probably could do the same.